# preforming x = x+1 in Tkinter using def add():

Tags: tkinter

I have an error every time i try to this program.

```
from Tkinter import *
def returnCodeno():
    print 'no'
    choice = choice + 1
    textEnter('no')
root = Tk()
choice = 0
Yes = Button(root,text = 'Yes',width = 15, command = returnCodeno)
Yes.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and I get this error every time I try clicking yes

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Stephen Tafoya\Desktop\Stanley parable text based\stanley2.py", line 6, in returnCodeno
choice = choice + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'choice' referenced before assignment
```

any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Question heading is different,content is different...

Comment: If you really want to make `choice` **global** then use `global choice` in `add` method. Also,what is `textEnter` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to access the module level variable `choice` in `returnCodeno` instead of creating a new local one, so you have to use the `global` statement.

**Example:**

```
from Tkinter import *
def returnCodeno():
    global choice
    choice += 1
    print choice

root = Tk()
choice = 0
Yes = Button(root,text = 'Yes',width = 15, command = returnCodeno)
Yes.pack()
root.mainloop()
```